# Google is indexing future dates on my codeigniter datepicker

Tags: codeigniter, datepicker, google-index

If I do a google search for "harbour holidays 2 strand" then it returns my clients site www.padstow-self-catering.co.uk

The problem is that google has decided to index and future date which can be seen from the datapicker on the right sidebar.  Nearly all searches for specific holiday properties has this issue and the future date is different for each.

I have no idea why this is happening?

Comment: If you mean it's showing the dates as the description below the result in the Google listings, you should use a [`<meta name="description" content="Blah blah blah" />` element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#The_description_attribute).

Comment: I mean if you click the link google returns then it shows the correct page but the datepicker on the right shows a future date, such as December 2016.  It should show todays date.

Comment: How does your page determine the date? Is it passed in a GET parameter or something? (thats the only way Google can affect this.... I get the feeling this is your code, rather than Google's indexing-system).

Comment: The date is determined from the URL.  Would using rel="nofollow" on the datepicker navigation fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The "2016" comes from the URL that's been indexed:

```
http://www.padstow-self-catering.co.uk/properties/map/46/2016/12
```

Presumably somewhere there's a page with that URL on, and Google indexed that.

Personally I'd probably make the date picker parameters URL parameters instead:

```
http://www.padstow-self-catering.co.uk/properties/map/46?year=2016&month=12
```

... or remove it entirely from your links. Either way, it's not that Google has "decided to index" pages for a future date - they're just pages.

(Note: I work for Google, but have nothing to do with web search. This answer should not be seen as being an "insider" post in any way, nor as representing the view of Google.)